# Gridview finding control in gridview

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How to find control of gridview in user defined Function 
...
this throws

```
DataSet ds = objSelectAll.Paging(PageSize, PageNumber, USERID, ROLEID);

if (Session["Username"].ToString() == "admin")
{ 
    foreach (GridViewRow row in UserRoleGridView.Rows)
    {
        ImageButton ImgEditbtn = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("EditButton");
        ImageButton ImgDelbtn = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("DeleteButton");

        DataSet dsusr = objSelectAll.UserBasedPaging(PageSize, PageNumber, USERID, ROLEID);
        UserRoleGridView.DataSource = dsusr.Tables[1];
        UserRoleGridView.DataBind();

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the current Row is Data Row or Header Row.

for checking the row type you need to write

```
 if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
// do what ever you want
}
```

Now Your code look like

```
  foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
      // do what ever you want

    }
}
```

I hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in UserRoleGridView.Rows)
                {
                    ImageButton ImgEditbtn = (ImageButton)row[row.RowIndex].FindControl("EditButton");
                    ImageButton ImgDelbtn = (ImageButton)row[row.RowIndex].FindControl("DeleteButton");
                DataSet dsusr = objSelectAll.UserBasedPaging(PageSize, PageNumber, USERID, ROLEID);
                UserRoleGridView.DataSource = dsusr.Tables[1];
                UserRoleGridView.DataBind();
    }
```